# How do I shut down or reboot my LG G6?

Tags: lg

I've been very happy with my G6 so far. It has one feature that's a bit odd - there's no power button, instead you double-tap the screen to wake it and double-tap it on the launcher desktop to put it to sleep.

How do I reboot the phone, if I need to? And how do I turn it off? It'd be nice to do that before removing the sim card (which is on the same drawer as the SD card.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fingerprint reader on the back is exactly the power button. Hold it down for 10 sec and your G6 will reboot.